VS Code reopens closed Python script and matplotlib figures after restart
I'm facing a strange issue with VS Code on my Windows 11 machine. A few days ago, I ran a simple Python program that generates matplotlib figures in a for loop. The code does not involve any multiprocessing or multithreading; it simply iterates 8 times, creates a figure using matplotlib, and shows it.
I closed the program and exited VS Code after it completed running. However, when I reopened VS Code later, it started to automatically display the matplotlib figures again, as if the program was still running. As I manually close the figures, VS Code proceeds through the loop, and once all figures are closed, the IDE itself also shuts down.
There is no output in the terminal window, and it doesn't seem like the script is explicitly running, but the figures keep appearing.
Here's what I've tried so far:

Restarting VS Code.
Restarted laptop
Killing any lingering Python processes in Task Manager.
Clearing VS Code's .vscode folder and cache.
Checking my workbench.startupEditor setting in VS Code to ensure that no files are reopened automatically.

I can run/debug another Python script in parallel while the unwanted figures are opened.
I ran the same program on a different machine, no such problem.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any suggestions on what could be causing this?

Hello, can you try using different interpreters to see if it works? Or reinstall matplotlib via pip uninstall matplotlib and pip install matplotlib.

Have you tried to explicitly set the backend to Agg (non-interactive) ?
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')


no, I did not. And, now if I modify the file, it does not matter as the VSCode is keep running the old file.
